# How to use outline-minor-mode to hide some exam class exercises in AUCTeX

Tags: auctex, exam

I use the `exam` document class in AUCTeX to write exams for my students. I want to use the features provided by the `outline-minor-mode` to hide all the exercises I have finished  and only show the one I am editing.
In the exam class there is `\question` macro for writing exercises. 
Here is an example :

```
\documentclass{exam}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question % exercise N°1
     statement of exercise 1
\question % exercise N°2
    statement of exercise 2
\question % exercise N° 3
     statement of exercise 3
\end {questions}
\end{document}
```

I want for example to hide the statements of exercise 1 and 3 when I edit the statement of exercise 2!
So I have add `\question` to the heading list of AUCTeX with the variable `TeX-outline-extra` like this:
`M-x (setq TeX-outline-extra '(("\question" 1)))`
But `\question` is not recognized as a heading as expected!

Comment: Try doubling, tripling, or quadrupling the backslash. Also I don't think you can type `M-x (setq...`; you probably did something else.

Comment: There is a good answer in this post from @Tyler: [https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27829/how-to-use-outline-minor-mode-to-hide-some-exam-class-exercises-in-auctex/27880#27880](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27829/how-to-use-outline-minor-mode-to-hide-some-exam-class-exercises-in-auctex/27880#27880)

Comment: Yep that's what I meant about quadrupling your backslash. Good you got it working. Want to leave what you learned as an answer, so that this question doesn't remain open and it can help someone who searches for a similar question here in future?

Comment: I don't know how to  mark this question as answered !!

Comment: You can't :-) What you can do is write your own answer, and then "accept" it. I recommend doing this as well: it will help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this answer is given by @Tyler in this post

[http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27829/how-to-use-outline-minor-mode-to-hide-some-exam-class-exercises-in-auctex/27880#27880](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27829/how-to-use-outline-minor-mode-to-hide-some-exam-class-exercises-in-auctex/27880#27880)

You haven't properly escaped the regexp for "\question". It should be:

```
"\\\\question\\b"
```

This is a string, and in order to encode a single backslash in a string, it needs to be escaped with a backslash of its own. And in order to use a literal backslash in a regexp, it must be escaped with another backslash. So to get a regexp to match a single literal `\` from a string, you need to use `\\\\`.

The `\\b` at the end of the string matches the end of a word, which is the regexp `\b`.

This will only work if `\question` appears at the beginning of the line. That's why @arashesbati added the `[ \t]*`, which makes the regexp match `\question` with any number of tabs or spaces before it on a line.

Setting the outline level to 1 seems a bit high, I think you might end up folding everything below the question into the question, including subsequent sections. So probably more useful to use something like:

```
("[ \t]*\\\\question\\b" 4)
```

Finally, it looks like AucTex only reads this at the beginning of a session, and subsequent changes to take effect until you restart. So the best way to make this addition is probably via `M-x customize-variable TeX-outline-extra`. That way, you know the variable will be changed before AucTex is loaded the next time you start Emacs. In my case, this variable is defined as:

```
'(("[   ]*\\\\question\\b" 4) ("[   ]*\\\\\\(bib\\)?item\\b" 7) ("\\\\bibliography\\b" 2))
```